# WIX equivalent of a C# textbox?

Tags: user-interface, wix, dialog

I'm staring at this page wondering which control is a textbox. 
Seems like it should be obvious, but I don't see it.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_control.htm

Also, is there a built-in "Browse" button to select a file from disk? 
Or do you have to code all that yourself?

Thanks,

Neal

Comment: Note that you're looking at the wix2 documentation, while you're most likely using wix3! See http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/main.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found the textbox (second one below).  It was a matter of setting the Type="Edit".

When I was looking at the web page mentioned, I was first looking only at "children" thinking that I would see a textbox there.

```
<Control Id="Description2" Type="Text" X="135" Y="140" Width="220" Height="20" Transparent="yes" 
    NoPrefix="yes"   Text="Full path to settingsFile:" />
<Control Id="UserSettingsFileName" Type="Edit"
    X="140" Y="150" Width="160" Height="80" Property="SettingsFilename"
    Text="C:\Path\SettingsFileGenerator.xml">
```

The initial value of the edit/box was not set to the text I specified.  Any ideas on that? Do I have to set the property value outside of the control?

But if there is an reasonably easy-to-use "browse"/file-picker, I'd like to know about that too.

Answer (score 3):

The wix sources contain a `BrowseDlg.wxs` file. This file defines the dialog which is used in `WixUI_InstallDir` to allow the user to enter or browse for the install path, which is exactly the type of functionality you need.

It looks like you just have to use the Type "PathEdit". You also have to give the property where you want the result to be stored, in this case `_BrowseProperty`:

```
<Control Id="PathEdit" Type="PathEdit" 
   X="25"
   Y="202"
   Width="320"
   Height="18" 
   Property="_BrowseProperty"
   Indirect="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `BrowseProperty` and `PathEdit`, it exclusively navigates through folders and not individual files. It seems necessary to develop a distinct Event or Custom Action to achieve this functionality.

A blog I came across demonstrates a similar approach:
https://etechgoodness.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/wix-add-browse-for-file-capability-to-installer/